# Passing string between 2 C# application instances

Tags: c#, single-instance

I built a media player, that media player is associated with several media file types.
Every time that a user opens a media file, I check if my player is open.
I managed to prevent opening two instances but I want to pass the file path to the already opened instance.

I am using mutex to prevent opening and I have been trying to use SendMessage to pass strings.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: There are a whole raft of technologies available to you including WCF, MSMQ and Remoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx), i.e.`NamedPipeServerStream` & `NamedPipeClientStream`. Some general overview is avaibale [here](http://wyday.com/blog/2010/multi-process-c-sharp-application-like-google-chrome-using-named-pipes/) as well, although in your case basic write-to-temp-lock-file/read-from-temp-lock-file might not be such a bad idea.

Comment: This requires framework 3.5 and I need this to be FW2.

Comment: @user1689604 What's FW2? See the edited, would a temp file suffice?

Comment: framework2. writing to a temp file wont suffice: first, how do i know when to read from it? second, its really messy.

Comment: Lock files suffice for Tomcat, TeamCity, Vim, etc. I don't think your media player is more special than that. Plus names pipes are not .NET 3.5, the C# wraper is, you can do a bit of `CreateNamedPipe` PInvoke magic, see the 'here' link example.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the first question- I still need to know when to read it.

Comment: Write on `Mutex` failure, read on `FileSystemWatcher` event? I'd still go for some named pipe pinvoke though.

Comment: When i automate the sending process, it doesnt work. any idea why?

Comment: Not sure what is 'automate the sending process', are you trying the PInvoked named pipe? Does the sample client/server from wyDay's zip work? Anyway, try asking a new question -- comments are not meant as a chat.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way is to create a WCF service into your media player.
You will can communicate easily with it.
See the [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class